# CFMX6.1 deploying on Websphere 6.1 Server: Error 500: The Security service is not available

Tags: coldfusion, websphere

I am deploying a CFMX6.1 application to a Websphere 6.1 server. The server starts up without any errors but when I goto the CF Adminstrator page (or any cf page) I get the following error:

> Error 500: The Security service is not available.

Can you deploy CFMX6.1 to WS6.1? My searches on the internets seem to say yes and no. As far as the error goes I normally end up at a page that lists the same error with stacktrace but no answers. Am I just searching using the wrong question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have heard of that issue with unsupported JDKs, check your environment and see what JDK CF is likely finding.

Is there a reason you need CF 6.1? From the updater tech notes it seems like it was a pain to get running with WebSphere and you needed a special updater from IBM to get the patches.

[ColdFusion MX 6.1 Updater Release Notes](http://www.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/coldfusion/mx61updater/releasenotes_cfmx61_updater.html)

Comment: Unfortunately it is what I am stuck with.